# Can a Python script using xlwings be deployed on a server?

Tags: python, xlwings

We currently have a python script launched locally that periodically generates dozens of Excel files using Xlwings.

How can it be deployed on a cloud server as an ETL that would be linked to a job scheduler, so that no human action is needed anymore?

My concern is that Xlwings requires an Excel license (and a GUI?), which is not usually available in the production server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way that you can currently do what you have in mind is to install Excel, Python, and xlwings on a Windows Server: xlwings was built for interactive workflows.

You might want to look into OpenPyXL and XlsxWriter to see if you can create the reports by writing the Excel file directly, as opposed to automating the Excel application, as xlwings does.

Comment: However, there's also xlwings Server, albeit for a different use case (use Excel locally, but install Python on the (lInux) server).